# Java to serve HTML on LAN

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jetty

My end goal is to get a packaged webserver ( maybe jetty) that will serve LAN clients a form (index.html), and upon clicking the submit button have the server receive the form content via post then parse the id's and values into a MS Access DB (I have no choice about the DB).

The project must run on JRE7 Win8. The project and any required servers must not require a install routine that requires a exe (ie jars are ok).

I did some reading on jetty and experimented with trying to get it to serve the form without success. I also had someone show me spring & thymeleaf but that was too complex for my level of skill.

My html tags for example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="streetAddress" placeholder="Street Address"/>
```

Is there a simpler way to do this and if so some example code would be great.

Ideally the fieldname:value pairs would end up in a hashmap.

Thanks

AG

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-form-data.htm , Check example from this page.

Comment: I saw that link, but a few issues with that: (a) it doesnt show how to serve existing html file, and (b) it uses Tomcat - which wont install on the LAN because of the installation restrictions (Jetty however will)

Comment: Its probably also worth pointing out that I am trying to do this with IntelliJ and Gradle.